# Как обратится к элементу формы из обработчика события, которое вызывается в другом потоке?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

В программе создаются и удаляются объекты, в них есть события и метод который запускается в отдельном потоке. В этом методе который будет работать в отдельном потоке будет вызвано это событие. В форме нужно по этому событию обновить контрол.
Вот код в упрощенном виде:

```
class class1
{
   //событие на которое вешается SomeEventHandler
   public event EventHandler event1;
   public class1()
{
   new Thread(Method1).Start();
}

private void Method1()
{
    //выполняется в фоновом потоке
    event1?.Invoke();
}
}
class Form1
{
    SomeEventHandler()
    {
         //взаимодействие с формой
         //сюда нужно добавить что то, что будет взаимодействовать с формой но из основного потока
    }
}
```

Как видно SomeEventHandler будет вызван в другом потоке, но тогда в этом обработчике нельзя обратится к контролу формы. Как это обойти?

Конструктор class1 тоже запускается не в основном потоке, не из интерфейса.

Comment: Я тебе написал ответ, но я дополню. В моём примере class1 это Worker. Тебе не в SomeEventHandler нужно делать синхронизацию, а в class1  (Worker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экземпляр класса `Worker` в данном примере должен создаваться в UI потоке, потому что в его конструкторе мы получаем контекст синхронизации .

Если не хочется в класс, содержащий код, который работает в другом потоке пихать контекст синхронизации, то просто внутри метода обработчика в классе окна (`SomeEventHandler`)вызывай метод [Invoke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423500/3786094) (кстати, там ответ написал Джон Скит - автор книг по C# и .NET технологиям)

В `WPF` и `Windows Forms` разные реализации `SynchronizationContext`. То есть в зависимости от технологии он по разному перенаправляет выполнение в `UI` поток (если речь о `UI`).

Заметь, что без

```
_sycnContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
```

В консольном приложении не заработает, так как `SynchronizationContext.Current` там будет `null`.

**Worker.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace WorkerLib
{
    public class Worker
    {
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext;

        public Worker()
        {
            _syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
        }

        public event EventHandler Started;

        public event EventHandler Completed;

        private void StartOperation(object state)
        {
            _syncContext.Post(OnStarted, null);

            // Делаем работу
            Thread.Sleep(1250);

            _syncContext.Post(OnCompleted, null);
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(StartOperation);
        }

        private void OnCompleted(object state)
        {
            var handler = Completed;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void OnStarted(object state)
        {
            var handler = Started;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Windows Forms

**MainForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WorkerLib;

namespace WinForms_SyncContextExample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private readonly Worker _worker;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _worker = new Worker();
            _worker.Started += (sender, args) => infoLabel.Text = "Запустили работу";
            _worker.Completed += (sender, args) => infoLabel.Text = "Работа завершена";
        }

        private void WorkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _worker.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Console

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using WorkerLib;

namespace SyncContextExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Worker worker = new Worker();
            worker.Started += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Запустили работу");
            worker.Completed += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Работа завершена");
            worker.DoWork();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не работает. Все равно обработчик события вызывается не из основного потока.У меня различие в том что функция должна вызываться именно через Thread и форма не знает кто вызывает событие, она передает делегат, и там уже его добавляют к событию. Ну и обработчик не в виде лямбды. Это же влиять не должно?

Comment: То что я выложил 100% работает. Без полного кода сказать что-то нельзя. Значит ты где-то ошибся. Скинь код, я могу посмотреть.

Comment: Лямбда выражения тут вообще не при делах. Я их использовал просто для краткости.

Comment: Да, действительно работает если отдельно создать. Даже добавил передачу делегата через другой класс для верности. Спасибо, пока грузить своим кодом не буду, пока сам попытаюсь найти ошибку.

Comment: Сделал совсем как у меня в тестовом проекте. И да оно опять вываливается. Первый созданный поток "смог обратится к форме", а следующие уже нет. Суть в том что воркеров множество. Я могу скинуть решение, только куда?

Comment: @shooter9688, нарпимер, на яндекс диск или любой другой. Или ещё куда-то.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-xiUXf34jTIamhaR05DSDFUZWs  Вот проект на котором только код из вашего ответа,но для множества фоновых потоков. Он себя ведет аналогично моему. Один раз бывает получается из другого потока изменить контрол, потом уже нет.

Comment: @shooter9688, всё, я понял. Проблема тут в том, что `Worker` создаваться должен в UI потоке, потому что в конструкторе `Worker` мы получаем контекст синхронизации. Можно переделать этот весь код так, чтобы контекст синхронизации получался из UI потока и передавался в конструктор класса `Worker` так же, как делегаты.

Либо вообще в этих классах не использовать контекст синхронизации, а просто в обработчиках в `UI` выполнять код через вызов `Control.Invoke` (в моём ответе есть ссылка).

Обновлю ответ, нужно указать, что Worker в данном примере должен создаваться в UI потоке.

Comment: То есть нужно в UI потоке создать SynchronizationContext и передать его, в данном случае, конструктору WorkerMaker который далее будет раздавать его создаваемым Worker? Я попробовал и это не помогло. Мне нужно создавать этих воркеров именно вне UI потока. Если нужно проект с правками https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-xiUXf34jTIMDk3bkNTNzdmYTA

Comment: @shooter9688, нужно просто передавать `SynchronizationContext.Current` не нужно создавать никаких полей, которые инициализируются до вызова конструктора класса `Form1`. То есть: `new WorkerMaker(Started, Stopped, SynchronizationContext.Current)`. Проверил, всё работает. В `Windows Forms` не нужно создавать новый контекст синхронизации, в моём примере есть проверка на null и создание нового только для того, чтобы это работало в `Console Application`.

Comment: спасибо! Теперь работает. А насчет консоли, так она вроде не обижается на многопоточный доступ.

Comment: @shooter9688, так-то оно так, но класс `Worker`  в конструкторе получает контекст синхронизации, а если в консольном приложении он получит Null, то приложение просто не будет вообще работать, так как `_scyncContext` будет `null`, поэтому там создаётся новый

Answer (score 0):

Создайте синглтон, общий для всех потоков, и положите в него экземпляр вашей формы. Тогда другой поток сможет взаимодействовать с ней по ссылке.

*Однако будьте осторожны:* может произойти такое, что с одним полем взаимодействуют сразу оба потока, т.е. решение непотокобезопасно.

Comment: В смысле создать экземпляр класса Form1? Как тогда манипуляции с ним повлияют на тот экземпляр который представляет настоящий интерфейс? Или получить копию ссылки на форму? Но через какие ссылки на экземпляр бы я не обращался, все равно будет обращение из не основного потока.

Comment: @shooter9688 Получите ссылку на настоящий интерфейс и засуньте его туда, куда имеют доступ оба ваших потока.